# Babel preset minify TypeError: _interopRequireDefault is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am getting this error on a few test cases with Enzyme running babel-preset-minify plugin. It's erroring next to a `const myConst ={ ... }`

```
 TypeError: _interopRequireDefault is not a function
```

These are the only options I have on my babel config file

```
presets: [
    [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
            'debug': false,
            'useBuiltIns': 'usage',
            'corejs': 3
        }
    ],
    ['@babel/preset-react'],
    [
        'minify',
        {
            'evaluate': false
        },
    ],
],
```

Comment: With recent deployment of babel 7.13.0 this issue was coming https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/12863#issuecomment-783994353 but now this has been fixed with this https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/12863#issuecomment-784131383 change. I believe because of recent change this might be occurring. For More detail https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/12863